# camera2api auto capture current preview frame

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

Uses Camera 2 API on Android

For real time image processing I have a listener set up to do some image processing that gives a boolean output on whether to capture an image or no. Currently I am using `camera2Raw` example that has a `takePicture()` when a button is clicked. How can I ensure that the same frame that I processed is captured and no additional ones are captured. Please do help me out. Thanks

[Link to camera2Raw](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Raw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you made a capture in your captureSession, the current frame will be capture and go through onCapturePictureComplete() method from the current callback associate to your capture:

```
  mCaptureSession.capture(mPhotoRequestBuilder.build(), YourCallback, null);

private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback YourCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
                                   @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                   @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {

        //get the iso and time exposure from the picture
        Integer iso = result.get(CaptureResult.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY);
        long timeExposure = result.get(CaptureResult.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME);

        Log.i(TAG, "[mHdrCaptureCallback][HDR] Photo: " + mHdrIndex + " Exposure: " + timeExposure);
        Log.i(TAG, "[mHdrCaptureCallback][HDR] Photo: " + mHdrIndex  + " ISO " + iso);

    }
};
```

In the example above I made a capture and when it was complete, the Capture callback is call. There I just print the values of Exposure and ISO from the image result. But, when you take a picture, the onImageAvailable Listener from your current ImageReader will be called too, and there is where you will have the current frame and the image to save it.

Look at your example in Google:

```
/**
 * This a callback object for the {@link ImageReader}. "onImageAvailable" will be called when a
 * JPEG image is ready to be saved.
 */
private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnJpegImageAvailableListener
        = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {

    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
        dequeueAndSaveImage(mJpegResultQueue, mJpegImageReader);
    }

};

/**
 * This a callback object for the {@link ImageReader}. "onImageAvailable" will be called when a
 * RAW image is ready to be saved.
 */
private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnRawImageAvailableListener
        = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {

    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
        dequeueAndSaveImage(mRawResultQueue, mRawImageReader);
    }

};
```

Hope that it will help you and now you know a bit better how the save image process work's with camera2, let me know if I can help you in something else!